# Why is my dynamic sitemap.xml not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sitemap

I am using nextjs14. According to nextjs docs I create an sitemap.js file inside my app directory for create an dynamic sitemap but when I go to http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml I see 404 not found

[image]

Here is my code

```
 app
   sitemap.js


export default function sitemap() {
  return [
    {
      url: 'https://acme.com',
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: 'yearly',
      priority: 1,
    },
    {
      url: 'https://acme.com/about',
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: 'monthly',
      priority: 0.8,
    },
    {
      url: 'https://acme.com/blog',
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: 'weekly',
      priority: 0.5,
    },
  ]
}
```

But when I create an sitemap.xml inside my app directory I can see only static content not getting any content from  sitemap.js

[image]

Comment: have you tried to build first ?

Comment: There is no reason to include `lastModified`, `changeFrequency` or `priority` in your sitemap.  Search engines don't use that info.  It just ends up bloating your file. The URL is enough along with any hreflang, video, and image info you want to include.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out that there was no issue with my code. For localhost, the correct URL path for the sitemap will be http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml/0.1. However, when working on production, it will be http://domainname/sitemap.xml.